# How to read/set default install location on android programmatically?

Tags: android

I know that the default install location of apps in Android can be retrieved by using adb method by invoking:

```
adb shell pm getInstallLocation
```

and can be changed by using:

```
adb shell pm setInstallLocation
```

But my question is how do we achieve this programmatically(using Android API or Java code).

Answer (score 1):

The [App Install Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) page of the Android Developer's docs provides information on setting the app install location and potential caveats.

To do so, you need to specify the `installLocation` in your manifest, like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

Your options are:

- **preferExternal**: Install on the device's external storage whenever possible (not guaranteed)
- **auto**: Default to internal storage, but allow the user to move it to external storage
- **internalOnly**: Only allow installation on the device's internal storage.

You cannot set this in the app's code, as by the point any code executes the application has already been installed.