# How to get path/location of adb in android programatically

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to get path/location of adb in android -
by this code -

```
String adbLocation = System
        .getProperty("com.android.screenshot.bindir");
if (adbLocation == null)
 {
    adbLocation = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME");
    if (adbLocation != null) {
            adbLocation += File.separator + "platform-tools";
 }
```

Now getting the path /location in log by

> Log.e("adbpathTag - ","adb: -"+adbLocation);

but the output I am getting is -

> adbpathTag -     adb: - null

how I can get right Path of adb here ?? Is there any other way through which I can get adb path/location

Comment: `adb` is a tool you use on a computer to aid with debugging an app on your phone.  Why are you trying to find it on your phone??

Comment: I am trying to get screenshot of my android device with the help of ddmlib on android.. I am trying to implement the code on android : link of java code is - [link](http://www.androidadb.com/source/pdn-slatedroid-read-only/eclair/sdk/screenshot/src/com/android/screenshot/Screenshot.java.html)

Comment: You can't use adb for that. I suggest you search SO for [_android take screenshot_](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+take+screenshot) - there are hundreds of questions with answers.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084979/how-to-read-set-default-install-location-on-android-programmatically ...this can help u